# Should I connect the Vout coupling capacitor of a common drain amplifier next to RD or RS?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, common-drain

When designing a common drain amplifier of the circuit linked below, I need to attach a coupling capacitor to the Vout of the circuit. I think a capacitor connected to Vout should be just below RD, is this correct? I've attached an incomplete version with Vin and its coupling capacitor below, Thanks for any help.

[image: Mosfet circuit]

[image: Incomplete drain Amplifier]

Comment: Don't go removing your schematics from the question.  This site is intended to be useful to future readers not just the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When designing a common drain amplifier of the circuit linked below, i need to attach a coupling capacitor to the Vout of the circuit. I think a capacitor connected to Vout should be just below RD, is this correct? I've attached an incomplete version with Vin and its coupling capacitor below, Thanks for any help.

If the coupling capacitor is connected to the drain, then the circuit is a common source amplifier.

If the coupling capacitor is connected to the source, then the circuit is a common drain amplifier.

Both are amplifiers, but with different characteristics. The common source amplifier will give greater voltage gain. The common drain amplifier will give little to no voltage gain, but will give great current gain, and low output impedance.

Choose the amplifier topology that fits your requirements.

Comment: ahh, so a drain amplifier in this case would be the coupling capacitor in green?

Comment: @Thne a _common_ drain amplifier. Yes.